# Fetch data from server only when getBounds value is outside previous returned value else restrict

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am implementing technique called: "Viewport Marker Management" defined in this link : [too many markers: viewport management](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=en#viewportmarkermanagement)

As described, i am listening to the change in map and when map is "idle", it calls callback where i am getting bounds value and querying to server to get list of data to populate as a marker in the map.

The problem here is that, i am fetching data everytime there is change in map bounds. And i want to only call server, when bounds value is higher then the previous value, in other words, **when user zooms out i need to get more data so need to call server, but when user zooms in do not want to call to server to fetch data. Also i need to fetch data when user pans.**

My current code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Map.map, 'idle', function(){
            var bounds = Map.map.getBounds();
            query_params.bounds= bounds;

            AppAction.getMapLocationList(query_params);
});
```

What i am doing in the code:

1) Map.map is a reference to map defined in other js file and is
    equivalent to map

2) query_params.bounds sets a new property in
        query_params object called bounds which will have value acquired
        from getBounds() function

3) AppAction.getMapLocationList(query_params) this is basically passing
    object to other js file where i have generated url from the object
    property to fetch data from server.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to see the function where you do your calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'd do it. The LatLngBounds has a `contains` method that you can use to see if a bounds object contains a LatLng object.

So you can get the *last* bounds North-east and South-west coordinates and see if the map bounds (after zooming) contains them or not. This way you can deduce if user zoomed in or out.

```
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2, 6.17);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var lastBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Set the last bounds to the map bounds (once)
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {

        lastBounds = map.getBounds();
    });

    // Listen for the zoom changed event
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {

        // Get the new map bounds
        bounds = map.getBounds();

        // Get the last bounds NE and SW coordinates
        var ne = lastBounds.getNorthEast();
        var sw = lastBounds.getSouthWest();

        // Check if current bounds contain the last bounds NE and SW coordinates
        if (bounds.contains(ne) && bounds.contains(sw)) {

            // Map bounds after zoom changed contains the last bounds NE and SW coordinates => you zommed out
            console.log('zoomed out');
        }

        // Set last bounds to current bounds
        lastBounds = bounds;
    });
}

initialize();
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/wnrjt3b5/)</kbd>

Comment: there is a slight problem. 

 'var lastBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Set the last bounds to the map bounds (once)
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
        lastBounds = map.getBounds();
        //console.log(lastBounds); has value which want effect value of lastBounds outside this function.
    });

//console.log(lastBounds) outside does not receive inside value. '

How can i solve this problem.

Comment: sorry, Please refeer to this link for proper formatted code where problem is shown: https://jsfiddle.net/rosnk/5pc2kvss/

As you can see lastBounds value inside the function does not effect outside. This may be due to asyn. Any suggestions are welcome. thanks in advane.